# confused about $\Bbb F_3(\alpha) \cong \Bbb F_3/\langle x^3+2x+2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

What is the form of, and what method can be used to find $\Bbb F_3(\alpha)$

if $\Bbb F_3(\alpha) \cong \Bbb F_3[x]/\langle x^3+2x+2\rangle$ ?

I know how to do this for more simple polynomials, namely using this method  [trying to understand the relation between quotient rings and Field extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702527/trying-to-understand-the-relation-between-quotient-rings-and-field-extensions/2702539?noredirect=1#comment5583044_2702539). However I'm confused as to what approach to take for higher degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by *find*? $\mathbb{F}_3(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to a finite field with $27$ elements, since $x^3+2x+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$. What else do you need to *find*?

Comment: Presumably $\Bbb{F}_3$ should read $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ so that it contains the polynomial $x^2 + 2x + 2$ (and hence the ideal $\langle x^2 + 2x + 2\rangle$generated by that polynomial). @JackD'Aurizio: I suspect the OP wants to know how to describe the quotient ring and the multiplication in it in terms of a basis over $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Comment: Also does anyone know of any good websites ( apart from wikipedia) that teach you about Finite fields? I'm very new to them and I've been having difficulty finding good sites teaching about them.

Comment: @RobArthan yes exactly this is what i meant. could you shed any light on it for me ?

Comment: I've written up an answer. I hope that helps. The fact that $\Bbb{F}_3$ is finite isn't important for the points made in my answer.

Comment: @exodius I always recommend Keith Conrad's notes to people: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can prove is that any congruence class in $\mathbf F_3[x]/(x^3+2x+2)$ has a unique representative as the congruence class of a polynomial of degree $\le 2$, since by *Euclidean division*, for any polynomial $p(x)$, there exists a unique pair of polynomials $q(x)$, $r(x)$, such that
$$p(x)=(x)(x^3+2x+2)+r(x),\qquad \deg r(x)\le 2.$$

Thus if we denote $\alpha$ the congruence class of $x$ mod. $x^3+2x+2$, we have
$$p(\alpha)=r(\alpha)= a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2\quad\text{for some }\enspace a, b,c\in \mathbf F_3.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $R = \Bbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^3 + 2x + 2\rangle$ is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_3$ of dimension $3$, generated by (the images in $R$ of) $1$, $x$, $x^2$. To see that this is closed under multiplication, note that the relation $x^3 = -2x - 2$ holds in $R$ and use this relation to simplify any polynomial in $x$ to a polynomial of degree at most $2$. To see that $1$, $x$ and $x^2$ are linearly independent, note that a polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ cannot have the form $p(x)(x^ 3 + 2x + 2)$ unless $a = b = c = 0$ (and $p(x) = 0$). If we write $\alpha$ for (the image in $R$ of) $x$, then as $x^3 + 2x + 2$ happens to be irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$, we use the traditional notation $\Bbb{F}(\alpha)$ for $R$ viewed as a field generated by the element $\alpha$.